# XML manipulations

Tags: php, xml, json, perl, xmlserializer

I'm writing a php application to manipulate XML files.
I tried Perl XML serializer/unserializer to convert 
XML->php obj->json for manipulation
Then convert the json back to xml to print out.

Here is a sample of the original XML

```
<module name="AssignId" active="true"  description="user description">
  <dict name="params">
    <entry key="Adds">
     ...
    </entry>
  </dict>
</module>
```

converted to JSON look like this:

```
{"name":"AssignId","active":"true","description":"add draggable class to figure","dict":{"name":"params","entry":[{"key":"Adds" ...
}}
```

and the end result XML looks like this:

```
<name>AssignId</name>
    <active>true</active>
    <description>add draggable class to figure</description>
    <dict>
        <name>params</name>
        <entry>
            <XML_Serializer_Tag>
                <key>Adds</key>
                  ...
            </XML_Serializer_Tag>
        </entry>
    </dict>
</name>
```

Here are my 2 classes

```
class JSON_toXML {

    var     $jsonObj,
            $phpObj,
            $serializer;

    public function __construct($options, $file_path) {
        $this->serializer = new XML_Serializer($options);
        $serializedDoc = $this->serializer->serialize(json_decode($file_path));
        if ($serializedDoc === true) {
            $this->jsonObj = $this->serializer->getSerializedData();
        } else {
            $this->jsonObj = NULL;
        }
    }
    public function print_obj() {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo($this->jsonObj);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}


class XML_toJSON {

        var     $phpObj,
                $jsonObj,
                $unserializer;

        public function __construct($options, $file_path) {

            $this->unserializer = &new XML_Unserializer($options);
            $unserializedDoc = $this->unserializer->unserialize($file_path, true);
            $this->phpObj = $this->unserializer->getUnserializedData();
            $this->jsonObj = json_encode($this->phpObj);
        }

        public function print_phpObj() {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($this->phpObj);
            echo "</pre>";
        }

        public function get_phpObj() {
            return $this->phpObj;
        }

        public function print_jsonObj() {
            echo $this->jsonObj;
        }

        public function get_jsonObj() {
            return $this->jsonObj;
        }

    }
```

I wonder how to keep the end result XML the same format as the original?
Maybe there are better ways to do it?
Thank you!!!

Comment: will you please check the JSON "in the middle" Code and verify that it is correct?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be able to distinguish between an attribute and an element, but your format does not convey that information. You need to start by changing your format, perhaps to something like the following:

```
{
   "element": "module",
   "attribs": {
      "name":        "AssignId",
      "active":      "true",
      "description": "add draggable class to figure"
   },
   "children": [
      {
         "element": "dict",
         "attribs": {
            "name": "params"
         },
         "children:" [
            ...
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: It probably won't help because I don't have control over how XML_unserializer parse this thing from XML to Json via json_encode().
Probably writing a parser myself?